# How can I debug this error: "Cannot Convert Lambda Expression to String"?

Tags: c#

I am trying to debug the following code, but it is not working.

I upload this pic 
http://i68.tinypic.com/2rqoaqc.jpg

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {   
         string input = "code1,code2,#c55+35+97#g,coden,code3,code4,#c44+25+07#gcoden";

         string output = Regex.Replace(
             input, 
             "#c(.*?)#g", 
             m => "#c" + m.Groups[1].Value.Split('+').Sum(int.Parse) + "#");

         Console.WriteLine(output);    
    }
}
```

And these are the errors I am getting:

**ERROR 1:**

> 'int int.Parse(string)' has the wrong return type (CS0407) -

**ERROR 2:**

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' and 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' (CS0121)

**ERROR 3:** - Cannot convert m "lambda" to string

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type (CS1660)

Comment: Please copy all of the error messages into the question.

Comment: Is `**m**` your attempt to highlight `m` in the code, or is it the actual code?

Comment: is the hightlighted

Comment: I would suggest reading up on [Regex.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx). You are not passing in parameters of the correct type. Like the error says, it is expecting a string, not a lambda expression.

Comment: @dbc I left the `m` by Error 3 since I felt it made it clearer which lambda and line the error refers to. I don't think it should have been edited out. That statement probably should either be rephrase using `m`, or the entire sentence should be removed completely because as it currently is, it doesn't add any extra information to the error statement directly below it.

Comment: @TotZam - OK, reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an explicit lambda rather than `int.Parse()`:

```
    string output = Regex.Replace(
        input,
        "#c(.*?)#g",
        m => "#c" + m.Groups[1].Value.Split('+').Sum(v => int.Parse(v)) + "#");
```

Notice I replaced `int.Parse` with `v => int.Parse(v)`.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bGi01P).

Interestingly enough, this compiles and works as desired in c# 6.0:

```
    string output = Regex.Replace(
        input,
        "#c(.*?)#g",
        m => "#c" + m.Groups[1].Value.Split('+').Sum(int.Parse) + "#");
```

Sample [Roslyn fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gfuDcb).  I'm not sure where this change is documented, maybe under [New Language Features in C# 6: Improved overload resolution](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6):

> There are a number of small improvements to overload resolution, which
>   will likely result in more things just working the way you’d expect
>   them to. The improvements all relate to “betterness” – the way the
>   compiler decides which of two overloads is better for a given
>   argument.
>
> One place where you might notice this (or rather stop noticing a
>   problem!) is when choosing between overloads taking nullable value
>   types. Another is when passing method groups (as opposed to lambdas)
>   to overloads expecting delegates. The details aren’t worth expanding
>   on here – just wanted to let you know!